# Ajax infinite scrolling gallery is adding the same images multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a simple gallery pages that adds elements when you reach the bottom, I'm using Django to render an html snippet from the backend and trying to append it to my page with javascript.

for some reason when I scroll I often see the same pictures appearing multiple times.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm doing it? I can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
(function(){
    var Gallery = {
        page: 1,
        init: function(){
            this.bindScrollEvent();
            this.cacheDOM();
        },
        cacheDOM: function(){
            this.$image_ul = $('ul.photos')
        },
        bindScrollEvent: function(){
            $(document).on('scroll', function(){
                if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                    this.getImages();
                }
            }.bind(this));     
        },
        appendImages: function(html){
            this.$image_ul.append(html);
            this.page+=1;
        },
        getImages: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : "/images/",
                type : "POST",
                data : {'query':'','page':this.page}, 

                success : function(html) {
                    console.log("success");
                    this.appendImages(html)
                }.bind(this),

                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    console.log("error");
                }.bind(this)
            });
        }

    };
    Gallery.init();
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you increment page only when you receive the response. Which means that before you receive response if you scroll down fast enough the request will fire with still same paging. So briefly just rewrite gallery class like this:

```
(function(){
var Gallery = {
    page: 0,
    init: function(){
        this.bindScrollEvent();
        this.cacheDOM();
    },
    cacheDOM: function(){
        this.$image_ul = $('ul.photos')
    },
    bindScrollEvent: function(){
        $(document).on('scroll', function(){
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                this.getImages();
            }
        }.bind(this));     
    },
    incrementPage: function(html){
        this.page +=1;
    },
    appendImages: function(html){
        this.$image_ul.append(html);
    },
    getImages: function(){

        this.incrementPage();

        $.ajax({
            url : "/images/",
            type : "POST",
            data : {'query':'','page':this.page}, 

            success : function(html) {
                console.log("success");
                this.appendImages(html)
            }.bind(this),

            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                console.log("error");
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }

};
Gallery.init();
})()
```